# Why does EF throw "NotSupportedException: The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation"

Tags: linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

```
int[] ids1 = { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] ids2 = { 1, 5, 6 };

var result = from a in ids1
             where a == ids2.First()
             select a;  
foreach (var item in result) ; //ok


var employees = from c in context.Employees.
                where c.EmployeeID == ids1.First() 
                select c;   
foreach (var item in employees); // NotSupportedException
```

When trying to call `ids1.First` within Linq-to-Entities query, I get an exception
*System.NotSupportedException: The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead*.

a) I don't understand why `First` can only be used as a final query operation, since in our example `First` is called on `IEnumerable<>` ( `ids1.First()` ) and not on `IQueryable<>`. In other words, `First` is called within Linq-to-Objects query and not within Linq-to-Entities query?!

b) Anyways, why must `First` be used as a final query operation, while `FirstOrDefault` doesn't have to be final query operation?

Thank you

REPLY:

> As for the difference between First() and FirstOrDefault() - I don't
>   know. Have you tried it, and does it work?

Yes it works

> No, First() is being called in the LINQ to Entities query. Your where
>   clause will be converted to: Where(c => c.EmployeeID == ids1.First())

a) I'm a bit confused now. I realize `ids1.First` is essentially called within Linq-to-Entities query, but the fact remains that `First` is called on `IEnumerable<>`, and as such `First` is called within Linq-to-Objects query, and this Linq-to-Object query is in turn called within Linq-To-entities query – at least that's how I understand it?!

Or are you implying that `First` is somehow called on `IQeryable<>`?

b) I realize that `(c => c.EmployeeID == ids1.First())` will get converted into an expression tree, but why isn't `ids1.First()` executed before the conversion happens?

c) Anyways, once the conversion into expression tree does happen, I assume when sql provider receives the expression tree of our `where` clause and tries to convert it into Sql command, this Sql provider doesn't have "the power" to execute `ids1.First` in order to get the result back ( which it would then put into Sql query  ), and hence the exception?!

**SECOND REPLY:**

a) I'm still confused why `ids1.First` isn't executed before the conversion into expression tree happens?! Namelly, with the following  clause

```
Where(c => c.EmployeeID == 2+3)
```

the expression `2+3` gets executed before this *Where* clause is transformed into expression tree! And `ids.First` is also an expression of sorts, so I would expect similar behavior?!

b) Sorry for being repetitive, but it's really bugging me whether my assumption - that
`First` is called within Linq-to-Objects query, and this Linq-to-Object query is in turn called within Linq-To-entities query – is correct?!

c) Perhaps I misunderstood your post, but are you implying that most other Linq-to-Object operators can be called on `IEnumerable<> E`,  even if `E` is contained within Linq-to-Entities query ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, `First()` *is* being called in the LINQ to Entities query. Your `where` clause will be converted to:

```
Where(c => c.EmployeeID == ids1.First())
```

That lambda expression will be converted to an expression tree.

Of course it's pretty simple to do that *outside* the query:

```
int firstId = ids1.First();
var employees = from c in context.Employees
                where c.EmployeeID == firstId
                select c;
```

which becomes more simply:

```
int firstId = ids1.First();
var employees = context.Employees.Where(c => c.EmployeeID == firstId);
```

As for the difference between `First()` and `FirstOrDefault()` - I don't know. Have you tried it, and does it work? Perhaps it's because `First()` will throw an exception when called on an empty sequence, and that behaviour may be hard to translate for some reason.

EDIT: Yes, the query provider *could* potentially look at that bit of the expression tree and work it out - but sooner or later you have to draw a line at how smart the query provider has to be. It's doing a lot of work already, and it's pretty easy for *you* to do the work here (as per my example above) - so why not do so?

Bear in mind that logically, `First()` is executed for each element of `context.Employees` - so it would need to *only* throw an exception on an empty collection if any rows existed - otherwise the `First()` call is never logically made. See, it's not *quite* as simple as you might expect :) In this case you happen to know that there *are* elements, so you can call `First()` with impunity beforehand - but the query provider can't.

EDIT: Reply to second edit...

a) The expression 2+3 is a compile-time constant. Change it to `x + 2` and the addition operation *will* be part of the expression tree. In particular, if you change the value of `x` (or `ids1` in your example) that will change the query - there's nothing you can do to change what 2+3 means.

b) It's not clear to me what you mean by that. The expression tree contained within the EF query includes a call to `Enumerable.First`, if that's what you mean.

c) It's up to the query provider to decide exactly what expression trees to support - and that goes for other method calls (e.g. `int.Parse`) as well as LINQ to Objects methods.

Comment: I apologize for keep dragging this topic ( will do my best to wrap it up quickly ), but could you see my second edit

Comment: @user702769: Okay, I've edited my answer again too. It's not clear to me what you're really trying to achieve though - just a better understanding of what's going on? (That's fine in itself, of course.)

Comment: "It's not clear to me what you're really trying to achieve though - just a better understanding of what's going on?" Mostly better understanding. Though I get the feeling I will have some trouble writing queries if I don't understand better what is going on under the hood. Anyways, thank you for your help

Comment: @user702769: Unfortunately with out-of-process LINQ providers there'll always be a certain amount of "try it and see" - you should always check the SQL generated as well. Basically it's great, but not a silver bullet :)