# How to handle error "method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation"

Tags: linq-to-entities

I want to retrieve data from the database in different tables by relation, but I get an error that I don't know how to handle.

```
int customer_id = int.Parse(this.comboBoxnamecustomer.SelectedValue.ToString());

a = (from c in db.Invoices where c.CustomerID == customer_id select new { 
        customerName = c.Customer.Name,
        ProductName = c.InvoiceItems
            .Where(x => x.InvoiceId == c.InvoiceId)
            .First().Product.ProductsName.Name
    }).ToList();
```

> Unhandled Exception: System.NotSupportedException: The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead.

The problem is with the `.First()` method, but if I remove it I can't pass to another table.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811544/why-does-ef-throw-notsupportedexception-the-method-first-can-only-be-used-as?rq=1

Comment: I'm not sure what your database structure is, but it seems like there is something else logically wrong with your query. Wouldn't c.InvoiceItems already only be those where the InvoiceItem.InvoiceId = Invoice.InvoiceId? If you've defined that relationship already, your use of Where seems redundant. Also do you really want the Product name of just the first item in each invoice the customer has?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Your solution, as the error states - is to use `FirstOrDefault`. This, however, will return `null` if the result of `ProductName` query is empty, meaning you'd get a `NullReferenceException` from `FirstOrDefault().Product.ProductsName.Name`.  This is solved by moving the property transform earlier in the query, before the call to `FirstOrDefault()`:

```
a = (from c in db.Invoices where c.CustomerID == customer_id select new { 
     customerName=c.Customer.Name,
     ProductName=c.InvoiceItems.Where(x=> x.InvoiceId==c.InvoiceId)
                               .Select(i => i.Product.ProductsName.Name)
                               .FirstOrDefault()
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is stating that you should use `FirstOrDefault()` instead of `First()`

Not sure what the question is

```
int customer_id = int.Parse(this.comboBoxnamecustomer.SelectedValue.ToString());

a = (from c in db.Invoices where c.CustomerID == customer_id select new { 
         customerName=c.Customer.Name,ProductName=c.InvoiceItems.Where(x=> x.InvoiceId==c.InvoiceId).FirstOrDefault().Product.ProductsName.Name
        }).ToList();
        dataGridViekryar.DataSource = a;
```

Of course this will throw an error if there isn't any items from your query (NullReferenceException)

Comment: The *consideration*, is invalid at best. The block `FirstOrDefault().Product` is a recipe for a `NullReferenceException`. I would say the exception thrown by `First()` is much more accurate.

Comment: @TheSolution I agree with you which is why I'm unsure where the suggestion came from

Comment: But the problem is different I guess it could be the language construct for Linq query expression that you can't use first() when creating a where clause. "Where" requires a value to compare not a possible exception.