# What can I do to improve the speed of this query?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a linq query that returns the last page a user looked at based on a table of page hits. The fields are simply `TimeStamp`, `UserID` and `URL` which are logged from user activity. The query looks like this:

```
public static IQueryable GetUserStatus()
{
    var ctx = new AppEntities();
    var currentPageHits = ctx.Pagehits
        .GroupBy(x => x.UserID)
        .Select(x => x.Where(y => y.TimeStamp == x.Max(z => z.TimeStamp)))
        .SelectMany(x => x);

    return currentPageHits.OrderByDescending(o => o.TimeStamp);
}
```

The query works perfectly but runs slowly. Our DBA assures us that the table has indexes in all the right places and that the trouble must be with the query.

Is there anything inherently wrong or BAD with this, or is there a more efficient way of getting the same results?

Comment: It seems to be a pretty simple query... I don't think it can be optimized very much.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't PLINQ (Parallel LINQ) a viable option here? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: You should log the SQL that is being generated from the query and analyse that to make sure it is efficient.

Comment: @GrawCube He's using Entity Framework or LINQ to SQL, so the grouping is actually done in the DB. PLINQ helps when you have multiple units of work that can be parallelized.

Comment: As said by w0lf. At max the final `OrderByDescending` could be done C#-side, but PLINQ wouldn't help here.

Comment: if you really need to improve the speed, the best appropach i think is to create a stored procedure in the database and execute the code there, then just call that stored procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you try to implement `DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC)` with LINQ? So all latest  records per user-group according to the `Timestamp`. You could try:

```
public static IQueryable GetUserStatus()
{
    var ctx = new AppEntities();
    var currentPageHits = ctx.Pagehits
        .GroupBy(x => x.UserID)
        .SelectMany(x => x.GroupBy(y => y.TimeStamp).OrderByDescending(g=> g.Key).FirstOrDefault())
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.TimeStamp);

    return currentPageHits;
}
```

So  it's grouping the user-group by `TimeStamp`, then it takes the latest group(one or more records in case of ties). The `SelectMany` flattens the goups to records. I think this is more efficient than your query.

Comment: Tim, thats definitely faster, at least 2 seconds shaved off a 10 second query, thank you. Had to change `.First()` to `.FirstOrDefault()` though

Comment: @GordonCopestake: why do you need `FirstOrdefault`? Since you are in the `user-group` there must be at least one record. If i group this by `TimeStamp` into a kind of sub-group i get at least one record.

Comment: `First()` gives a YSOD with `The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead.`

Comment: @GordonCopestake: ah, ok. Here is a question acc. this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232055/how-to-handle-error-method-first-can-only-be-used-as-a-final-query-operation

Comment: Thanks Tim, I'll mark your answer as correct as I guess there is no definitively correct answer to this type of question. At least no one has said "god that's an awful query, you've done it wrong!"

Comment: @GordonCopestake: if it's still to slow you should look at your database. There is probably the best place for optimizations. You could for example put an index on `UserID` and one on `TimeStamp desc` if that's not already  the case.

Comment: I'm assured that the indexes are already in place... But I wouldn't put it past them!

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

```
var currentPageHits2 = ctx.Pagehits
    .GroupBy(x => x.UserID)
    .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.TimeStamp).First())
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.TimeStamp);
```

But the speed should be the same.

Note that there is a subtle difference between this query and yours... With yours, if a *UserId* has two "max *TimeStamp*" *PageHits* with the same *TimeStamp*, two "rows" will be returned, with this one only one will be returned.

Comment: I don't know if the order is maintained in this case but in Linq-To-Objects this would be even better. `ctx.Pagehits.OrderByDescending(x=> x.TimeStamp).GroupBy(x=> x.UserID).Select(g=> g.First())`

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes, because in LINQ-to-objects the GroupBy is guaranteed to maintain order. But I think it gets lost "in translation"

Comment: @TimSchmelter By MSDN: `The query behavior that occurs as a result of executing an expression tree that represents calling GroupBy<TSource, TKey>(IQueryable<TSource>, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>>) **depends on the implementation of the type of the source parameter**. The expected behavior is that it groups the elements of source by a key value that is obtained by invoking keySelector on each element.`*

Comment: Acc. the "subtle difference", basically it's `DENSE_RANK OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC)` what is OP trying to do with LINQ. Then he wants to take only those which return 1, so the latest timestamp per user. To get the same behaviour you could replaceyour `Select` with `.SelectMany(x => x.GroupBy(y => y.TimeStamp).OrderByDescending(g=> g.Key).First())`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Quite a wonderful query :-) You should post a reply